# Enums unexpected token: DELETE

Tags: apex

I have defined the enums as:

```
public enum Method {
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
}
```

While saving above, I am getting the error:

> unexpected token: DELETE

Anyone have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you post your code? It could just be a syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word "delete" is a reserved keyword, and may never appear as a variable name or enum value. Traditionally, how I've worked around this is to include an X in the name, which I then remove later:

```
public enum HttpMethod { XGET, XPUT, XPOST, XDELETE }

public static void doAction(HttpMethod method, String endpoint) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod(method.name().removeStart('X'));
    // ... more code here
}
```

There's an entire list of [reserved keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm) that outline names that you can't use for purposes other than as specified in the language.